# click vs keydown page reload issues

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can anyone explain why using the searchbox and clicking enter works to hit controller, get results and load the right page but actually clicking the icon (which is called by the keypress) does not?

```
$('#searchbutton').on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/listing-search",
        data: $('#searchform').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            jQuery('#reload').html();
        }
    });
});

$("#searchbox").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13){
        $("#searchbutton").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: You can solve both problems by hooking to the `submit` event of the parent `form`. Then you only need a single event handler.

Comment: I don't see any glaring logical errors here.  Personally I'd need to see an example of it failing to debug more.

Comment: However `jQuery('#reload').html();` appears to be a typo.  You are not providing the new value for the html.

Comment: However, I didn't understand your logic completely but similar to @Taplar response. You will get nothing by `$("#searchbutton").click();` statement, either that should be `trigger` to `click` or any `click` function binding..

Comment: $("#searchbutton").click(); will case the click handler bound by jQuery to execture. @Rohit.007

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you want to say that as an answer I'll accept it -- onclick $('#searchform').submit(); was the way to go.

Comment: Sure, I added it for you. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can both avoid the issue and simplify the logic by attaching a single event handler to the `submit` event of the `form`, like this;

```html
<form id="searchform" action="/listing-search" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="searchbox" />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

```js
$('#searchform').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: this.method,
    url: this.action,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
      $('#reload').html();
    }
  });
});
```